# GPRS AT-commands for Siemens cell phone

Tags: at-command, gprs, atmega

I've a task - remote temperature monitoring. Hardware is atmega328 microcontroller, simple analog temperature sensor and old cell phone Siemens cx75 (this device has a GPRS module).  So, I'm looking for AT commands to send some bytes of data via GPRS from this phone. There are many documents about GPRS commands, but I've found just for modems insteed of cell phones.
Maybe someone can help me? Or is it easier to use another solution?

UPDATE:
I've some progress:
First of all I set PDP context:

```
at+cgdcont=1,"ip","mts"  
OK
```

Then

```
at+cgatt=1
OK

at+cgact=1
OK
```

It's ok, I've been attached to packet domain service and PDP context
So, what should I do next? I have tried some modem commands, such as

```
at+cipstart=0,"tcp","178.xxx.xxx.xxx","8001"
```

but I've got

```
ERROR
```

Comment: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=104936.0  Read the long post by pylon, half way down the page.  It explains the issues nicely.  I don't know what you've got on your microcontroller.

Comment: Thanks so much! I should search for other way of remote controling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @S List 's link, there is no opportunity of gprs-connection using clear atmega328. It's seem the easiest way is to use GRPS-shield.